# Strategies for handling or avoiding race conditions

Tags: database, multithreading

I'm working on a .NET application where I off-load my DB work (save operations) to a separate thread (inspired by how NodeJS handles IO operations). A save operation comes down to this (using Entity Framework):

```
public void Save(Customer customer)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        using (var entities = new MyEntities())
        {
            var persistedCustomer 
                = entities.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Number == customer.Number);

            if (persistedCustomer == null)
            {
                persistedCustomer = new DBCustomer();
                // set properties
                entities.Customers.AddObject(persistedCustomer);
            }
            else
            {
                // set properties
            }

            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
    });
}
```

So, in essence:

- check if entity already exists in the DB
- if not, create a new one
- if it does already exist, update the existing one

Where this sometimes breaks down is when two calls to the Save method are made at the same time. Both threads see the entity doesn't exist yet and they want to do an insert. A standard race condition.

How would you go about fixing this? Any experience with this?

I could implement a retry mechanism, but was wondering if there are other options. A simple retry could of course overwrite certain properties that the previous save had updated.

Comment: One problem with your example is that this code assumes `Customer` (the one passed into your `Save` function) is a thread safe object.  Either you need to make `Customer` immutable, or you need to use some other kind of locking or memory barrier.  I suggest creating an immutable copy.

Comment: ...since Entities are by definition mutable objects, you should never *ever* pass an Entity across a thread boundary, which I'm afraid is what you're doing here.

Comment: "inspired by how NodeJS handles IO operations" that's not how node works.

Comment: @AlexWiese I'm open to constructive criticism (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) but just saying something is wrong doesn't help me or anyone else here learn how (in this case) Node.js does work.
That being said, it's been a while. I guess what you're trying to say (correctly) is that my code does a fire-and-forget on another thread, while Node.js will allow other request when waiting for IO to finish, but it won't continue the execution of the current piece of code.

Comment: Sorry yes I should have expanded. It does naturally async IO rather than using multiple threads .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problems like this are often solved with queues.

If you are saving same customer, you insert it into one [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Then there is one thread that reads the queue sequentially and does the update on each item read. Only place where the synchronization between threads occurs is in insertion to the queue and that can be done both fast and without risk of deadlocks.

Comment: I use producer consumer queues quite a bit in my multithreaded code.  System.Collections.Concurrent is a wonderful namespace added in to the framework.